# Find out which shapes are overlapping on inline shapes in a Word document using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a macro that needs to detect if there are any overlapping shapes (arrows, circles, etc.) on inline shapes (pictures). I've tried looping through all the inline shapes and then checking if any shapes overlap them. However, I've run into an issue because inline shapes don't have the `.top` and `.left` properties. How can I modify my approach to account for this?
[Inline shape with shapes on top of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBAR2.png)

This is what I tried, I tried converting all the inline shapes to shapes first and then determined overlapping shapes. But this way doesn't really working as it is considering shapes that are not overlapping.

```
Dim WordDoc As Document
Set WordDoc = Documents.Open(path)
Dim pge As Page
Dim i As Long, x As Long, g As Long
Dim inShp As InlineShape, shp As shape, overlay As shape

Dim groupShapes As Variant
ReDim groupShapes(0 To 0) As Variant

With WordDoc
    For i = .InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set inShp = .InlineShapes.Item(i)
        If inShp.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
            With inShp.ConvertToShape
                .ZOrder msoSendToBack
                .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapThrough
            End With
        End If
    Next i
    For Each shp In .Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
            ReDim groupShapes(0 To 0) As Variant
            groupShapes(UBound(groupShapes)) = shp.Name
            g = 0
            For Each overlay In .Shapes
                If overlay.Type <> msoPicture Then
                    If CheckOverlap(shp, overlay) = True Then
                        ReDim Preserve groupShapes(0 To UBound(groupShapes) + 1) As Variant
                        groupShapes(UBound(groupShapes)) = overlay.Name
                        g = g + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next overlay
            If g > 0 Then
                .Shapes.Range(groupShapes).group
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
End With
```

Overlap function:

```
Function CheckOverlap(primaryShape As shape, secondaryShape As shape) As Boolean
    Dim primaryTop As Double, primaryBottom As Double
    Dim secondaryTop As Double, secondaryBottom As Double
    
    ' Get the coordinates of the primary shape
    primaryTop = primaryShape.Top
    primaryBottom = primaryShape.Top + primaryShape.Height
    
    ' Get the coordinates of the secondary shape
    secondaryTop = secondaryShape.Top
    secondaryBottom = secondaryShape.Top + secondaryShape.Height
    
    ' Check for overlap
    If secondaryBottom >= primaryTop And secondaryTop <= primaryBottom Then
        CheckOverlap = True
    Else
        CheckOverlap = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: InlineShapes have a [`Range.Information`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.information) property which can give you the horizontal and vertical position